# How to lauch an external file from Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, file, external

I'd like to open a pdf file simply double-clicking on one element of a QListWidget.
I created a batch file to open Acrobat Reader (reader.bat), but I want a specific pdf file:

```
void MainWindow::on_FileListWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
        QFile SelectedModel(Current_Path  + "/Template/" + item->text());
        QString FileName;
        FileName = (Current_Path  + "/Template/" + item->text());
        ::system("e:\\reader.bat");
}
```

1) I don't know what's could be better from QFile or QString in order to identify and choose the file from the QListWidget;
2) I dont' know how to add the file to the command to open Acorbat Reader (in the shown line I'm able to open the program but not my file).
Any idea?

Comment: QProcess is the Qt way to start a process. If you want to use the standard Application take a look into QDesktopServices::openUrl()

Answer (score 17):

You can use Qt native methods to achieve this behaviour by calling

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("someFilePath"));
```

See [QUrl::fromLocalFile()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html#fromLocalFile) and [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl)

(Refer to [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/28917-Open-an-external-file-from-qt) post)

Comment: I would like to use this in combination with a QTemporaryFile. How do I know when the program is finished and I can delete the temporary file again?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file://path/to/file"));
```

This not only takes care of opening the file with the default application (if the `file://` scheme is used), but will also open a web URL with the default browser (if the `http://` or `https://` scheme is used) or will open it with the default email client in case of a `mailto://` scheme. It works with other schemes like `steam://`, `itunes://` etc. as well.

Comment: Solved! I used QDesktopService::OpeUrl and all works as I desidered. Thanks

Comment: Another problem related to:
 QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///c:/MyDir/MyPDF_Files.pdf", QUrl::TolerantMode));
Works perfectly. I'd like to replace all quote inside brackets with an item double-clicked:
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(Current_Path  + item->text(), QUrl::TolerantMode));
Something like that: How can I do?

Comment: Are you asking for how to get the current directory that the user is in? You can do it using QUrl(QDir::currentDir() + item->text())

Comment: Exactly! thanks
This is the final:
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(Current_Path + "/MyDir/" + item->text()));